# subscript indices must be either positiveintegers less than 2^31 or logicals

Tags: algorithm, octave

SOS i keep getting errors in the loop solving by finite difference method.

I either get the following error when i start with `i = 2 : N` :

```matlab
diffusion: A(I,J): row index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1
error: called from
    diffusion at line 37 column 10  % note line change due to edit!
```

or, I get the following error when i do `i = 2 : N` :

```matlab
subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
error: called from
    diffusion at line 37 column 10   % note line change due to edit!
```

Please help

```matlab
  clear all; close all;

% mesh in space
  dx = 0.1;
  x  = 0 : dx : 1;

% mesh in time
  dt = 1 / 50;
  t0 = 0;
  tf = 10;
  t  = t0 : dt : tf;

% diffusivity
  D = 0.5;

% number of nodes
  N = 11;

% number of iterations
  M = 10;

% initial conditions
  if x <= .5 && x >= 0   % note, in octave, you don't need parentheses around the test expression
      u0 = x;
  elseif 
      u0 = 1-x;
  endif

  u = u0;

  alpha = D * dt / (dx^2); 

  for j = 1 : M

      for i = 1 : N
          u(i, j+1) = u(i, j )            ...
                      + alpha             ...
                        * ( u(i-1, j)     ...
                            + u(i+1, j)   ...
                            - 2           ...
                              * u(i, j)   ...
                          )               ;
      end

      u(N+1, j+1) = u(N+1, j)             ...
                    + alpha               ...
                      * (                 ...
                          u(N, j)         ...
                          - 2             ...
                            * u(N+1, j)   ...
                          + u(N, j)       ...
                        )                 ;

    % boundary conditions
      u(0, :) = u0;
      u(1, :) = u1;
      u1      = u0;
      u0      = 0;

  end 


% exact solution with 14 terms

  %k=14   % COMMENTED OUT

  v = (4 / ((k * pi) .^ 2))             ...
      * sin( (k * pi) / 2 )             ...
      * sin( k * pi * x )               ...
      * exp .^ (D * ((k * pi) ^ 2) * t) ;

  exact = symsum( v, k, 1, 14 );
  error = exact - u;

% plot stuff
  plot( t, error );
  xlabel( 'time' );
  ylabel( 'error' );
  legend( 't = 1 / 50' );
```

Comment: I recommend that you step through your program in the debugger, and examine the value of the various variables involved just before the error is thrown. This will reveal the error in your logic. The error message says exactly where the error happens, you can set a breakpoint on the line before and see it all happen. This is a much faster and easier way to debug than asking here, and you’ll learn more to boot. Good luck!

Comment: Note that 0 is not a positive integer. MATLAB starts indexing at 1.

Comment: if i start indexing at i=2:N it says 'subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals error'

Comment: you are also using `i+1` as index, what happens when `i` is equal to `N` ?  Same for `j`. Maybe you want to initialize the full matrix N+1,M+1 to zero ? You are creating a vector with `x=0:dx:1` but your are testing it is as a scalar. Replace `elseif` with `else`.

Comment: I agree with Cris, but moreso, it's always worth cleaning up your code to make it easier to find bugs. I have taken the liberty of cleaning it up for you as an example. Run it again and see how much easier it is to look for errors. An advantage of splitting long equations into many lines is that octave will tell you exactly which line is at fault; though I would always try to simplify such lines via a subfunction or intermediate variables anyway to make things clearer. Also, your question mentions i = 2:N in both scenarios. Typo?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the edited code I cleaned up for you above and study it.
Don't underestimate the importance of clean, readable code when hunting for bugs.
It will save you more time than it will cost. Especially a week from now when you will need to revisit this code and you will not remember at all what you were trying to do.

Now regarding your errors. (all line references are with respect to the cleaned up code above)

**Scenario 1:**

In line 29 you initialise `u` as a single value.

If you start your loop in line 35 starting with `i = 2`, then as soon as you try to do `u(i, j+1)`, i.e. `u(2,2)` in the next line, octave will complain that you're trying to index the *second* row, in an array that so far only contains *one* row. (in fact, the same will apply for j at this point, since at this point you only have one column as well)

**Scenario 2:**

I assume the second scenario was a typo and you meant to say `i = 1 : N`.
If you start with `i=1` in the loop, then have a look at line 38: you are trying to get element `u(i-1, j)`, i.e. `u(0,1)`. Therefore octave will complain that you're trying to get the *zero* element, but in octave arrays start from *one* and zero is not defined. Attempting to access any array with a zero will result in the error you see (try it in a terminal!).

**UPDATE**

Also, now that the code is clean, you can spot another bug, which octave helpfully warns you about if you try to run the code.

Look at line 26. There is NO condition in the `elseif` leg, so octave looks for the next statement as the test condition.

This means that the `elseif` condition will always succeed as long as the result of u0 = 1-x is non-zero.

This is clearly a bug. Either you forgot to put the condition for the `elseif`, or more likely, you probably just meant to say `else`, rather than `elseif`.